# Changing parallel line length to split polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, length, parallel

I have a polygon which I want to split with a selected line with a parallel line.

I have made the parallel line but it's lenght is not enought to split the polygon.

It necessary to be parallel with the other line. Can I change the line lenght without I change the position of the line?

I use QGIS 18.2[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are asking. Are you trying to split the polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to extend your parallel line while keeping its orientation (angle), please try following steps.

Before this, you need to make sure "Advanced Digitizing Panel" is displayed by View | Panels |(check) Advanced digitizing panel.

Then
[image: Digitizing]

1. Toggle Editing on your line layer
2. Add Feature
3. Enable advanced digitizing tools
4. Click your first point
5. Click your end point, then you can see a green line extends out
6. Follow this green line and click at your desired point

You can also set the angle to a fixed number, and lock, in the "a" entry of the Advanced Digitizing Panel. (I do not know which way is easier for your case.)

To do this easily, setting Snapping Option is highly recommended.

Comment: I tried this but I can not click on point 4 and 5. It wont be parallel with the other line if I click as near as I can.

Comment: How can I click on the point?

Comment: Then, can you set your Snapping Option to include your layer of the parallel line? To do it, `Settings | Snapping Options`  then `Layer selection -> all visible layers` and `Snap: To vertex`, `Tolerance: 5 pixels` It will draw your mouse to the existing nodes.