# Understanding difference between Polygon and Multipolygon for shapefiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, multipart

Creating Scratch layer gives me a choice between Polygon and Multipolygon, so I started wondering how should I make use of them.

[image: New Temp Scratch Layer]

Reading a new book *"Mastering QGIS"* (through [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220897/115) by Joseph to [What does buffer mean in QGIS Voronoi dialog?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220894)), authors' comment was `"ESRI shapefiles store geospatial data in multi- type geometry, so using multi- type geometry is a good practice if you plan on converting between formats."`

How should I choose one of them (Polygon or Multipolygon) when I create a new polygon layer?
(I had confused multi-polygon with multipart-polygon, so I used to choose Polygon.)

One recent situation I have come to choose Polygon/Multipolygon was [Changing parallel line length to split polygon in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/parallel-line-length) in which I draw a dummy polygon as a background layer. Working mainly on shapefiles it seemed I was supposed to choose Multipolygon, although I needed only one polygon. In this case what I needed was simple polygon geometry without any attribute (Not sure this example make any distinction.)

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to help you choose.  Please **edit** the question to specify what the scratch layer is due to contain.  Note that the book is misleading, in that shapefiles ***don't*** store multi-type geometries; instead they just do not make a distinction between single- and multi-part lines or polygons.

Comment: @Vince Thanks. I added a recent experience in which I needed to choose one of them. Not sure if this simplistic example makes any sense.

Comment: @Vince As to the latter part of your comment, is it that I do not have to worry about single- or multi-, as far as I am going to save the layer as shapefile to disk?

Comment: I converted all my Multipolygons to Ploygons in The GEOTIF gis changed them back after some time had occured I presume therefore this is what they should all be now

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your comment. My question was about vector polygon/multipolygon difference. Geotiff  - raster polygon - was out of my focus.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From a more formal point of view, I report the definition for both a polygon and a multipolygon (the following text and images come from [this](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355) document of the [OGC® Standards](http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/is), all credits to the cited source).

---

### Polygon

A Polygon is a planar Surface defined by 1 exterior boundary and 0 or more interior boundaries. Each interior boundary defines a hole in the Polygon.

The exterior boundary LinearRing defines the “top” of the surface which is the side of the surface from which the exterior boundary appears to traverse the boundary in a counter clockwise direction. The interior LinearRings will have the opposite orientation, and appear as clockwise when viewed from the "top".

The assertions for Polygons (the rules that define valid Polygons) are as follows:

1. Polygons are topologically closed;
2. The boundary of a Polygon consists of a set of LinearRings that make
   up its exterior and interior boundaries;
3. No two Rings in the boundary cross and the Rings in the boundary of
   a Polygon may intersect at a Point but only as a tangent;
4. A Polygon may not have cut lines, spikes or punctures;
5. The interior of every Polygon is a connected point set;
6. The exterior of a Polygon with 1 or more holes is not connected. Each hole defines a connected component of the exterior.

Below some examples of Polygons:

[image]

---

### Multipolygon

A MultiPolygon is a MultiSurface whose elements are Polygons.

The assertions for MultiPolygons are as follows:

1. The interiors of 2 Polygons that are elements of a MultiPolygon may not intersect;
2. The boundaries of any 2 Polygons that are elements of a MultiPolygon
   may not “cross” and may touch at only a finite number of Points;
3. A MultiPolygon is defined as topologically closed;
4. A MultiPolygon may not have cut lines, spikes or punctures, a MultiPolygon is a regular closed Point set;
5. The interior of a MultiPolygon with more than 1 Polygon is not connected; the number of connected components of the interior of a MultiPolygon is equal to the number of Polygons in the MultiPolygon

The boundary of a MultiPolygon is a set of closed Curves (LineStrings) corresponding to the boundaries of its element Polygons. Each Curve in the boundary of the MultiPolygon is in the boundary of exactly 1 element Polygon, and every Curve in the boundary of an element Polygon is in the boundary of the MultiPolygon.

Below some examples of MultiPolygons:

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you so much! It's so helpful. It must have taken a long time to summarize them in such a concise style, I cannot imagine how I could do it... So it seems to be a Collection set of Polygons, a Set of Surfaces, and supported by rather loose guideline in terms of topology (just my first impression). I will read and re-read linked material, it is very interesting!

Comment: I think you need to think about a multipolygon from a geometrical point of view. The most clear difference I see is that, starting from any location on the polygon surface, you may reach any other location on it, while for a multipolygon is not always true (see for reference the last examples for both categories in the above attached images).

Comment: Got that, thank you. Yes, single contiguous geometry or not,.. it makes big difference. Only remaining question I am struggling is, how we put a multipart object in terms of these distinction.

Comment: What makes the first MultiPolygon example belong there?

Comment: @Stijn the first example is a multipolygon because, in some cases, two points within it may be connected by a line that is not entirely contained within the polygon itself. This behavior is not allowed for a polygon, so it is a multipolygon.

Comment: @mgri: Are you talking about the left-most teardrop shape in the bottom image? It seems fully contiguous to me..

Comment: @mgri "two points within it may be connected by a line that is not entirely contained within the polygon itself. This behavior is not allowed for a polygon" then why the leftmost polygon in your first picture is a polygon? Shouldn't it be a multipolygon? How to define "within" ?

Comment: @mgri The first MultiPolygon make me confused. could you please give us more tips why it is a multipolygon? thanks a lot!

Comment: @mgri "two points within [a multipolygon] may be connected by a line that is not entirely contained within the polygon itself. This behavior is not allowed for a polygon" this is incorrect. a polygon can be concave.

Answer (score 31):

Shapefile polygons are constructed from one or more closed rings. If a shape has multiple rings, they can be exterior and interior (e.g., form a doughnut), or multiple exterior (e.g., island chain).
[image]

Of course, having multiple exteriors doesn't prevent having one or more interior rings on each shape.  The shapefile specification does state that:

1. Exterior rings must be clockwise, while interior rings must be counter-clockwise (this convention is known as *right-hand rule* since the shape would always be on your right-hand side as you walk the perimeter; unfortunately, it can also be known as *left-hand rule*, because the exterior rings follow the direction of a curled left hand with the thumb pointed upward from the top of the figure)
2. <strike>Interior rings must always follow the exterior ring they partition</strike> "The order of rings in the points array is not significant." (though in practice, at least for Esri-generated shapefiles, interior rings nearly always follow the exterior ring they partition)
3. Neither exterior or interior rings may overlap *or* share a common border (such features *may* be populated, but they are ***invalid*** and may cause *strange* geoprocessing failures).

Shapefiles do **not** make a distinction between these objects -- they are all polygons (and each geometry is associated with one dBase record).

However, some tools **do** make a distinction, QGIS being one of them.  If all you will *ever* have in a shapefile is simple **one-ring** shapes, then you can safely choose Polygon. If the shapes *may* contain "holes", it is *also* safe to choose Polygon.  If, however, *some* shapes may contain ***multiple exterior rings*** then you need to choose Multipolygon.

Comment: This is great in-depth summary about shapefile, Thank you so much! I now understand most of my past experience fall within usage of Polygon. In future I will use Multipolygon when I need to digitize holes, something like lakes. Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks for adding figure, so the one at the right-hand-side is the multiple exterior ring, for which I need to choose Multipolygon... not the one at the center with the hole!

Comment: I've got to go back and label them, but yes, the green polygon is the only Multipolygon

Comment: In the case of Two Rings (Multipolygon), would these two rings share the same record if we see the attribute table? (i.e. the shapefile has only one record)?

Comment: Yes, it is one geometry in one record

Comment: Sorry, dragging on and on... Additional test on `Scratch Layer | Multipolygon` function seems to create multiple records, one record per each feature. I am wondering if we are talking about the same thing. Have we gone into a discussion about multi-part polygon (which also fits to the description "two rings - one geometry in one record") from some point? Most likely I am mixing-up several technical terms (all new to me), though.

Comment: Another possibility; is this a bug of this Mutipolygon function?

Comment: Please create a new question. You will need to document your exact procedure. I have to say that it is more likely user error than a bug.

Comment: Am I correct when I think of the State of Hawaii as multipolygon?  Several (disconnected) islands comprise one state.

Comment: Most US states are multipolygons (all it takes is one coastal island), but HI, AK, FL, and MI are common examples.