# Natural Earth shapefile geometry-type

Tags: shapefile, natural-earth

Why do the Natural Earth shapefiles like ne_110m_countries_admin_0.shp have a geometry-type POLYGON, while it should be MULTIPOLYGON (at least when I understand [Understanding difference between Polygon and Multipolygon for shapefiles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225368/difference-between-polygon-and-multipolygon) correct. E.g. USA48 + Alaska + Hawaii is Multipolygon)

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because of this answer which shows how shapefile polygons can consist of disjoint parts: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225373/115

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shapefile specification](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) does not have a geometry type `Multipolygon`. The closest one is `Polygon` (with Z or M added). However, the USA is a multi-part polygon indeed meaning that it is represented as a single row in the shapefile yet the geometry itself consists of a few parts.

`arcpy` code run on shapefile:

```
> c = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("countries", "SHAPE@")][0]
> c.isMultipart`
True
> c.WKT[:30]
u'MULTIPOLYGON (((-155.581347656'
```

However, if you import the shapefile into some other more sophisticated storage format, such as PostGIS, the polygons would be stored using `Multipolygon` geometry type:

> Importing with configuration: ne_50m_admin_0_countries, public, geom,
>   C:\GIS\Datasets\ne_50m_admin_0_countries\ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp,
>   mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=4326
>   Shapefile type: **Polygon** PostGIS type: **MULTIPOLYGON[2]** Shapefile import
>   completed.

SQL in PostGIS:

```
select ST_AsText(Geom) from ne_50m_admin_0_countries
where sov_a3 = 'US1' and type = 'Country'
```

> MULTIPOLYGON(((-155.58134765625 19.01201171875,-155.625634765625...