# Ungrouping French Guiana from France in Natural Earth data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, natural-earth, france

I have a layer of countries, and I am trying to select all of Central and South America and export it to GeoJSON.

I am using this Admin 0 - Countries without boundary lakes from this link:
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/

For some reason, I cannot select French Guiana alone. When I select it (with either an expression or the point-and-click), France gets selected as well. I searched for French Guiana in the attribute table and I couldn't find it, I'm afraid it is grouped in with France somehow.

[image]

How do I separate French Guiana from France so I can select all of Central and South America and not select European France?

Comment: `For some reason, I cannot select French Guiana alone.` You won't be able to select French Guiana alone in that dataset, because it's regarded as being part of France.   see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Guiana.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thats because it is a [multipolygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225396/107424). You can use `Multipart to singlepart` located in Vector --> Geometry Tools to split them.

Comment: It is also because French Guiana is part of France (along with Reunion. etc)