# Creating polygons with "Create shapefile layer" always produce multipolygons instead of polygons when saving in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, multi-polygon

Not sure if is a bug or I'm missing something.
Every time i'm creating a new shapefile with "Create shapefile layer" i got a multipolygon instead of a polygon (at least is what I'm expecting).

Also got same issues,  when using an import of PostGIS table (with "Polygon" type geometry in db) and trying to add/save the polygons, I got an error with the message of unable to commit because different type inside the database compared to the default type which is created.

I ve tried different versions of QGIS (3.10,3.12,3.16) but seems to have all buggy behaviour.
I'm on Windows.

1. Creating a simple polygon as a Polygon type with rectangle tool
   [image]
2. Before saving: Getting the type of the polygon displays correctly a Polygon type
   [image]
3. After saving: The type is changing in Multipolygon without any warning.
   [image]

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225368/understanding-difference-between-polygon-and-multipolygon-for-shapefiles-in-qgis/225373

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shapefiles don't distinguish between Polygons and MultiPolygons, but many other programs do so it makes sense to "promote" polygons to multi (making simple Polygons into a MultiPolygon with one polygon in it) when exporting them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not really understand the meaning of *to "promote" polygons to multi when exporting them.*

Comment: A polygon is just a special case of a multi-polygon with only one polygon in it